# onnotification js callback not called on notification tap

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

Am building android application using cordova. for push notification am using FCM plugin. The notification is received in notification tray successfully. on click of notification app also opens.

The issue is with onNotification callback which never goes back. On looking into logs am able to find out that notification data is well parsed through application . FCMPluginActivity and FCMPlugin classes are getting called.

The only exception am getting in my code is of disabled native bridge.

Following is my notification json.

```
{  
"to" : "c54F_ChDDFk:APA91bG2Vq-pvNDAQgeT_2MEJbb-7BaD2uB8tocBm8y4oFaNu1tBQiu8jIiXWXi4SAMkI_GY7v6iPB7VT8rpNjKJ53FspuHlTxRdWsSkabfPyG4A5lhK-qFgw2MjGT8FQd46m3vBCcpz",
   "notification":{  
      "title":"Notification title",
      "body":"Notification body",
      "sound":"default",
      "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
   },
   "data":{  
      "param1":"value1",
      "param2":"value2"
   },
   "priority":"high",
   "restricted_package_name":""
}
```

am using following plugins.

```
cordova-plugin-battery-status 1.1.2 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-contacts 2.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.5 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.7 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 2.4.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.9 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 2.2.0 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.2.0 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.6 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
```

given below are the console logs after notification tap.

```
2019-04-03 17:33:55.423 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-04-03 17:33:55.423 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin: ==> FCMPluginActivity onCreate
2019-04-03 17:33:55.424 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin: ====Activity::::value from native storage=updatedValue
2019-04-03 17:33:55.426 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin: ====Activity::::updated value from native storage=updatedValue
2019-04-03 17:33:55.426 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin: ==> USER TAPPED NOTFICATION
2019-04-03 17:33:55.426 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: google.delivered_priority Value: high
2019-04-03 17:33:55.427 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam W/Bundle: Key google.sent_time expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value <null> was returned.
2019-04-03 17:33:55.428 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1089)
        at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity.onCreate(FCMPluginActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
2019-04-03 17:33:55.428 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: google.sent_time Value: null
2019-04-03 17:33:55.428 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Using measurement service
2019-04-03 17:33:55.428 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam W/Bundle: Key google.ttl expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
2019-04-03 17:33:55.429 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1089)
        at com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity.onCreate(FCMPluginActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: google.ttl Value: null
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: google.original_priority Value: high
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: param1 Value: value1
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: param2 Value: value2
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: from Value: 825633758297
2019-04-03 17:33:55.430 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1554293018484380%dfdafb68dfdafb68
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Key: collapse_key Value: sa.tfe.oneteam
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin: ==> FCMPlugin sendPushPayload
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   notificationCallBackReady: true
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   gWebView: org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl@85c8a92
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: collapse_key => sa.tfe.oneteam
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: wasTapped => true
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: google.original_priority => high
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: google.sent_time => null
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: google.delivered_priority => high
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: google.ttl => null
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: from => 825633758297
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: google.message_id => 0:1554293018484380%dfdafb68dfdafb68
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: param1 => value1
2019-04-03 17:33:55.431 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   payload: param2 => value2
2019-04-03 17:33:55.432 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FCMPlugin:   Sent PUSH to view: javascript:FCMPlugin.onNotificationReceived({"collapse_key":"sa.tfe.oneteam","wasTapped":true,"google.original_priority":"high","google.delivered_priority":"high","from":"825633758297","google.message_id":"0:1554293018484380%dfdafb68dfdafb68","param1":"value1","param2":"value2"})
2019-04-03 17:33:55.432 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/JsMessageQueue: Dropping Native->JS message due to disabled bridge
2019-04-03 17:33:55.455 4170-4177/sa.tfe.oneteam I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=214KB
2019-04-03 17:33:55.457 4170-4177/sa.tfe.oneteam I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=241KB, data=178KB
2019-04-03 17:33:55.493 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-04-03 17:33:55.494 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
2019-04-03 17:33:55.495 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
2019-04-03 17:33:55.496 4170-4170/sa.tfe.oneteam D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
2019-04-03 17:33:55.510 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 188936819
2019-04-03 17:34:00.514 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2019-04-03 17:34:05.517 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Session started, time: 188946840
2019-04-03 17:34:05.527 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity, _si=-1624274336331789161}]
2019-04-03 17:34:05.559 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Using measurement service
2019-04-03 17:34:05.560 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-04-03 17:34:05.567 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-04-03 17:34:05.568 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
2019-04-03 17:34:10.599 4170-31193/sa.tfe.oneteam V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```